# In Azure Data Factory Dataflow, how to get the row where the date is the latest?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In a step in the middle of a dataflow I have the following data.

[image]

I would need to filter this table to have only the row where the date is the latest one. I have tried with a Filtr activity, but it does not allow me to use max (I was trying to filter like: date==max(date)). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- `max()` function is an aggregate function. It can be used only in aggregate or window transformation. To filter the table with row having latest date, you can use **windows transformation**  to find the latest date accross the rows and then use **filter transformation** to filter the row having latest row. Below is the detailed approach.
- Take the **Window transformation**. In window settings, give the Window column as `max_date` and the expression as `max(date)`. If you want to find the latest row for each `provider` and `BaseCurrency`, you can give those fields in `over`.

[image]

**data preview of windows transformation:**

| Provider | date | baseCurrency abc | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ECB | 12/6/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 12/5/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 12/4/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 12/1/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 11/30/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 11/29/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 11/28/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |
| ECB | 11/27/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |

- Take the **filter transformation** and give the condition as `date==max_date`.

[image]

**Filter transformation data preview:**

| Provider | date | baseCurrency abc | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ECB | 12/6/2023 | EUR | 12/6/2023 |

- Using select transformation, select only the required columns.